# How to display 2 queryset list Frond end?(Django ListView get_queryset)

Tags: django, python-3.x, listview, frontend, django-queryset

I got 2 queryset list `expired_item` and `queryset` in Django ListView, but I don't know when item is expired(queryset is empty), how to display another list `expired_item` on frond end, no matter what I changed in abc.html, `expired_item` won't dispaly, I pasted my code as below:

```
class ABCListView(ListView):
    model = ABC
    ordering = ('name', 'skill_course')
    context_object_name = 'abcs'
    template_name = ''

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        # Omitted
        ......
        ......
        # Omitted
        expired_item = list(ABC.objects.filter(pk__in=aa).exclude(pk__in=z))
        queryset = Permit.objects.filter(pk__in=z)
        return queryset
```

And my html file of abc.html as below:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  </nav>
  <h2 class="mb-3">My Items list</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <table class="table mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Department</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for a in abcs %}
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ a.name }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ a.department.get_html_badge }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ a.status }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% empty %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h2 class="mb-3">My Expired Items list</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <table class="table mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Department</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for b in expired_item %}
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ b.name }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ b.department.get_html_badge }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ a.status }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% empty %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<div class="card-footer">
{% endblock %}
```

## Thanks so much for any advice!

Comment: send the second queryset through `get_context_data()` method

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use a normal django view. This Generic ListView is just created for the use of one list. Just pass both querysets in your context and render your template with that.

You could also use `get_context_data()` but this would be more or less hacky and not the qay I would recommend.

Comment: Do you know how to let 2 or 3 list values display on frond end by using get_context_data.